# symfony - adding a user to a group (sfGuardUserGroup) in a form

Tags: symfony1, symfony-1.4, symfony-forms

I'm trying to save some users in a custom admin form and I'd like to set them in a particular group, in the `sfGuardUserGroup`.

So If the user I've just created has an id of 25, then I'd expect an entry in the `sfGuardUserGroup` table with a `user_id` of 25 and a `group_id` of `8` (8 is my group id I want o add these users to.)

Could I do this in the form class, or in the `processForm` action?

I'm using doctrine and SF1.4

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do what you need:

```
<?php

class AdminUserForm extends sfGuardUserForm
{
  public function configure()
  {
    //customise form...
  }

  public function save($con = null)
  {
    //Do the main save to get an ID
    $user = parent::save($con);

    //Add the user to the relevant group, for permissions and authentication
    if (!$user->hasGroup('admin'))
    {
      $user->addGroupByName('admin');
      $user->save();
    }

    return $user;
  }
}
```

Comment: NOTE: You may be able to move the parent::save($con) line to the end to avoid doing 2 saves to the DB.

Comment: Ok, so this seems to work on initial creation of the user. But when i try to edit, I get the error: `SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry '31-3' for key 'PRIMARY'` If I then move the parent::save() to the end I get: `Notice: Undefined variable: user`

Comment: I added a check that should fix the integrity constraint violation

Comment: Ok, put in a check to see if the record `isNew`. Seems to work Just need a few more tests

Answer (score 0):

If you require this behaviour for all sfGuardUser's created you should put this logic in the model for sfGuardUser class. [example below]

```
// sfGuardUser class
public function save(Doctrine_Connection $conn = null) {

    if (!$this->hasGroup('group_name'))
        $this->addGroupByName('group_name', $conn);

    parent::save($conn);

}
```

If you require this functionality only on this specific form, you should put the logic within the form. Adding logic to the processForm action would be incorrect as you would be placing business logic within the controller.

Comment: The setting of the user to the group would be in a `save()` method?

Comment: I have added a code example. This will apply to all instances of sfGuardUser objects created as its in the model for that class

Comment: Thanks for the code. But it gives me an error: `Declaration of orderAdminProfileForm::save() should be compatible with that of sfFormObject::save()`

Comment: It would go in the sfGuardUser class (model not form). This is if you require the group to be added to all instances of an sfGuardUser. If not use the example provided by evilcelery